# SQL extract parent that haven't childs rows of type

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have this parent table[USERS]:

```
ID  |   NAME
1   |   Pippo
2   |   Pluto
3   |   Topolino
4   |   Paperino
```

and every user have addresses (one to many) 
this is childs table [ADDRESSES]:

```
ID  |   ADDRESS     |   TYPE    |   USER_ID
99  |   pippo@rmail |   R       |   1
100 |   pippo@qmail |   Q       |   1
101 |   pluto@rmail |   R       |   2
102 |   pluto@qmail |   Q       |   2
103 |   topo@mail   |   R       |   3
104 |   duck@mail   |   R       |   4
```

I want to SQL extract all users who have not a address of [TYPE] 'Q'.
My query should extract only "topolino" and "paperino" USERS rows...

How can I do this with SQL (or better TSQL)?

Comment: ...and your own attempts yet are?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.NAME
FROM USERS AS u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ADDRESSES AS a
                  WHERE u.ID = a.USER_ID AND a.TYPE = 'Q')
```

This will return all users not having an address of type `'Q'`. It may return users not related to any address though.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3769/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
   FROM [USERS] U
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (
         SELECT *
            FROM [ADDRESSES] A
            WHERE A.USER_ID = U.ID
               AND A.TYPE = 'Q'
      );
```

Another way would be using an `IN` clause

```
SELECT *
   FROM [USERS]
   WHERE ID NOT IN
      (
         SELECT USER_ID
            FROM [ADDRESSES]
            WHERE TYPE = 'Q'
      );
```